# tangential acceleration and angular acceleration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-velocity

> $$r= 2 \text{ m}$$
>
> $$a_{\text{tangential}}=\frac{\pi}{4} \text{ m/s}^2$$ for half a turn
>
> What is the angular velocity from rest of the circular path?

$$a_{\text{angular}} = \frac{\alpha}{r} = \frac{\frac{\pi}{4}}{2} = \frac{\pi}{8}$$

then using the formula

$$\omega^2 = 2{\alpha}\theta$$

I dont know if i should be using the distance($\theta$) to be $\pi$ or $2\pi$. The full distance is $2\pi$; however, the distance in which it was accelerating is $\pi$.

Comment: Next time use the suggestions given here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It should be $\pi$ as long as acceleration stops after half a rotation.